# How do you hide public IP addresses from websites with Python Selenium? proxy doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, proxy

I am trying to create bot with Python Selenium and want to hide my public IP address from websites. I am using proxy, proxy is working but it can't hide my public IP address.
I am checking it from this website:
https://browserleaks.com/ip

So IP changing with proxy but Public IP address is my home IP .  If this website can see it so all websites can see it.

```
options = {
            'proxy': {
                'https': 'https://' + str(i) + '',
                'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
            }
        }
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.accept_untrusted_certs = True
        chrome_options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={generate_user_agent()}')
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profiles")
        chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory='+profilename)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        #chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery");
        global browser
        service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)
        browser.delete_all_cookies()
        browser.minimize_window()
        browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
```

Answer (score 0):

"Proxies don't usually include DNS traffic, so your website requests still go to a third-party DNS server that can see your real IP address." [1](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/hide-ip-address-free/)

You can use a VPN with leak protection to solve your problem.

Comment: as I understand, it is about WebGL. But I can't disable WebGL on Google chrome